# Birkhoff Lattice theory notation question- probably easy to answer

Tags: notation, lattice-orders

In Lattice Theory p. 30 3rd edition:

Lemma 3. In any distributive lattice, every polynomial is equivalent to a join of meets, and dually:
$p(x_1,...,x_r)=\lor_{\alpha \in A}\{ \land_{S_\alpha} x_i \}= \land_{\delta \in D} \{ \lor_{T_\delta} x_j \}$

where $S_\alpha$, $T_\delta$ are nonempty sets of integers.

So far I understand this notation and thought I had proved the lemma pretty simply myself, but the first line of Birkhoff's proof threw me.
Here it is:

Proof : Each $x_i $ can be so written where $A$ or $D$ is the family of sets consisting of the single one element set $x_i$....

If A is the "family of sets consisting of the one element set $x_i$ "

Would A look like:
$A= \{ \{ x_i\} \}$
or $ A=  \{ \{ x_i \} ,\{ x_i, x_j\},\{ x_i, x_k\}, \{ x_i,x_j,x_k \}\}$

And then an example of an $S_\alpha$ would be for instance $S_{\{ x_i\} }$?
And what would be the members of this set?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this place in the book is written not very carefully. $A$ is the family of indices and in this case $A=\{\alpha\}$,  the one-element family, and $S_\alpha=\{x_i\}$.